# Envio de arquivo funcionando por form, mas não pelo postman

Tags: java, jersey, postman

Fiz um webservice com Java Jersey para envio de arquivos, quando tento enviar arquivos usando um form HTML, funciona, porém, quando tento enviar de um cliente ou no postman, é retornado um erro 500 com nullpointer.

UploadResource

```
@Path("/files")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public class UploadResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    public Response uploadImagem(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputString, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {

        String saveFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/CantinaRest/usuario/produtos/img/";

        File dir = new File(saveFolder);
        dir.mkdirs();

        String fileLocation = saveFolder + fileInputDetails.getFileName();

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;
            long file_size = 0;
            while ((bytes = fileInputString.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                file_size += bytes;
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            return new Response(1, "Imagem salva com sucesso: " + saveFolder);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new Response(0, "Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

O erro que é retornado pelo postman e pelo cliente Android:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    br.com.mobileti.cantinarest.rest.UploadResource.uploadImagem(UploadResource.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:147)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:190)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como está dando o mesmo erro no postman e no Android, então acredito que não seja problema com o Android, e sim com o webservice. o Erro da na linha `String fileLocation = saveFolder + fileInputDetails.getFileName();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema, o código está ok...
Eu esqueci de colocar o FormDataParam "file" no key do postman